# Qual metodo para fazer com que baixe todo o volume de mídia no Android?

Tags: java, android

Minha aplicação precisa que o usuário possa escolher em seu inicio se quer ouvir os sons do app ou não, pois é um aplicativo para também ser usado em sala de aula e nesse ambiente o volume do app deve estar zerado.

Assim criei um  `AlertDialog` para assim que o app ser executado o usuário decidir se baixa ou não o volume, assim:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActDinamica.this);
    dlg.setTitle("Bem Vindo!");
    dlg.setMessage("Você está em aula?");
    dlg.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Mute();
        }
    });
    dlg.setNegativeButton("Não", null);
    dlg.show();
```

Daí preciso configurar esse método `Mute();` para que o volume do áudio de mídia do celular vá para zero.

Método:

```
private void Mute() {
    // codigo para o volume zerar?
}
```

Obs: Encontrei apenas métodos para parar áudios específicos que estavam sendo executados...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve usar o [AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html), que é uma classe pública, que fornece acesso ao volume e controle do modo de campainha. Veja uma exemplo abaixo de como pode ser usado definindo, com o método `setStreamVolume()`, um volume específico:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 20, 0);
```

Para seu caso podes definir como `0` assim que o `AlertDialog` aparecer. Veja:

```
private void Mute() {
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);
}
```

Confira [a documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) para mais detalhes.

Comment: Isso não se encaixaria em um comentário?

Comment: Não só por mim, mas é melhor para evitar cliques, agrega mais na comunidade.

Comment: @FelipePaetzold olha novamente... fiz outra edição pegando lá da documentação. O que achou?

Comment: Ficou perfeito! Muito obrigado novamente! @Ack Lay

Comment: @TonyÁlaffe é você cara?! hehe.. Beleza!  Precisar, só colocar a duvida aqui mais detalhada e objetiva possível que o pessoal vai dar um jeito de ajudar. Abraços.

Answer (score 2):

No teu arquivo `Manifest.xml`, deves adicionar permissão para vibrar.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Para silenciar o celular, podes acionar o `AudioManager` da seguinte maneira:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
```

E para recuperar o volume, podes fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);

audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, maxVolume, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

Comment: Amigo, primeiramente houve um erro aqui **(em negrito)**: [AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) **context.** getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);], depois que corrigir esse erro se baseando na outra resposta dessa pergunta, voltou a não funcionar... Mas obrigado!